# $(file < $@) expands to nothing but it should not

Tags: file, makefile, gnu-make, variable-expansion

I wrote this make rule

```
$(COMPDIR)/%.d: $(COMPDIR)/%.cpp
# other code...
    $(file > $@,$(foreach path,$(file < $@),$(shell echo "$(path)" | sed 's!$(SRCDIR)/!$(COMPDIR)/!')))
# other code...
```

This should read the target file $@, tokenize its contents in the usual way of make ( whitespace separated words ), pass the tokens to sed and then save the result back into the same file.

If i put a literal file path in place of $@ the code works as intended, but if i leave it as it is it does just nothing.

I traced the root problem to be what i wrote in the title because i have verified that

```
    echo '$(file < $@)'
```

prints nothing.

The file is guaranteed to be populated because the only command that precedes the one i showed is the one that creates and populates it.

Any thoughts ?

EDIT 1: Some additional info

Software running on my system:

- GNU Make 4.2.1
- Bash 5.0.007 in POSIX mode ( invoked via /bin/sh )

Relevant variables defined in the makefile:

```
SHELL   ?= /bin/sh
SRCDIR  := src
COMPDIR := build/files
```

To respond to comments, here is the full rule with added test code:

```
$(COMPDIR)/%.d: $(COMPDIR)/%.cpp
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @ echo "Generating make rule for $(subst .d,.o,$@)"

# Generate recipe dependencies
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(subst $(COMPDIR),$(SRCDIR),$<) -MM -MT $(subst .d,.o,$@) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS)

# Patch the generated recipe to request source files from $(COMPDIR)
    $(file > $(@),$(foreach path,$(file < $(@)),$(shell echo "$(path)" | sed 's!$(SRCDIR)/!$(COMPDIR)/!')))

# Inject compilation instructions
    @ echo -e "\t$(CXX) -c -o $(subst .d,.o,$@) $^ $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS)" >> $@

# Tests
    @ echo -e "\n\n"
    @ echo -------------

    @ echo TARGET: $@

    @ echo -e "\n\n"

    ls -R $(COMPDIR)

    @ echo -e "\n\n"

    cat $@

    @ echo -------------
    @ echo -e "\n\n"
```

and the output it produces when make is called

```
ln -sf /home/qub1750ul/work/studentIngegneria/AssociateManager.BACKEND/src/auth/auth.cpp build/files/auth/auth.cpp
Generating make rule for build/files/auth/auth.o
g++ -o build/files/auth/auth.d src/auth/auth.cpp -MM -MT build/files/auth/auth.o -DDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -Ilib/json/single_include -Ilib/pistache/include -g -std=c++17



-------------
TARGET: build/files/auth/auth.d



ls -R build/files
build/files:
auth

build/files/auth:
auth.cpp  auth.d



cat build/files/auth/auth.d
build/files/auth/auth.o: src/auth/auth.cpp src/auth/auth.hpp \
 lib/json/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp \
 src/auth/../database/interface.hpp
-------------



ln -sf /home/qub1750ul/work/studentIngegneria/AssociateManager.BACKEND/src/server/server.cpp build/files/server/server.cpp
Generating make rule for build/files/server/server.o
g++ -o build/files/server/server.d src/server/server.cpp -MM -MT build/files/server/server.o -DDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -Ilib/json/single_include -Ilib/pistache/include -g -std=c++17



-------------
TARGET: build/files/server/server.d



ls -R build/files
build/files:
auth  server

build/files/auth:
auth.cpp  auth.d

build/files/server:
server.cpp  server.d



cat build/files/server/server.d
build/files/server/server.o: src/server/server.cpp src/server/server.hpp \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/endpoint.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/listener.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/tcp.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/flags.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/prototype.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/common.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/net.h lib/pistache/include/pistache/os.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/config.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/async.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/typeid.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/reactor.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/http.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/http_headers.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/http_header.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/mime.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/optional.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/http_defs.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/type_checkers.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/cookie.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/stream.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/peer.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/transport.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/mailbox.h \
 lib/pistache/include/pistache/view.h \
 lib/json/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp src/server/../auth/auth.hpp \
 src/server/../auth/../database/interface.hpp
-------------



ln -sf /home/qub1750ul/work/studentIngegneria/AssociateManager.BACKEND/src/main.cpp build/files/main.cpp
Generating make rule for build/files/main.o
g++ -o build/files/main.d src/main.cpp -MM -MT build/files/main.o -DDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -Ilib/json/single_include -Ilib/pistache/include -g -std=c++17



-------------
TARGET: build/files/main.d



ls -R build/files
build/files:
auth  main.cpp  main.d  server

build/files/auth:
auth.cpp  auth.d

build/files/server:
server.cpp  server.d



cat build/files/main.d
build/files/main.o: src/main.cpp src/auth/auth.hpp \
 lib/json/single_include/nlohmann/json.hpp \
 src/auth/../database/interface.hpp
-------------



rm build/files/server/server.cpp build/files/main.cpp build/files/auth/auth.cpp
g++ -c -o build/files/auth/auth.o build/files/auth/auth.cpp -DDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -Ilib/json/single_include -Ilib/pistache/include -g -std=c++17
g++: error: build/files/auth/auth.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/files/auth/auth.d:4: build/files/auth/auth.o] Error 1
```

Comment: what does `echo $@` give you - I assume there is a file name, and then (just for a test and assuming bash/shell) what does `cat $@` give you (should just print out the file contents) can you show all the output? Also you can try `ls $(COMPDIR)` (again assuming bash/shell) to show the contents of that directory

Comment: Are you sure you're using a new-enough version of GNU make?  The `file` function was introduced in GNU make 4.0.

Comment: Yeah, was just about to ask that as well - in-fact reading from files was introduced in 4.2, so 4.1 (and 4.0) only support writing to files). My vm has 4.1 and it complains about that function formatting - my other PC (with newer version) does not.

Comment: I would guess the existance of the `$(file >$@` truncates the file (to empty) before the `$(file <$@` reads it, so you get an empty result.

Comment: @ChrisDodd No, because the file remains untouched, as i show in the 1st edit

Comment: I cannot explain `make`'s behavior here.  It seems inconsistent with the documentation, but I suspect it relates to evaluation order.  On the other hand, this part of the recipe is pretty abominable.  GNU `make` functions should be used sparingly, if at all, where the wanted behavior is difficult or impossible to obtain by other means.  But the particular function call in question would be more clearly, easily, and efficiently expressed via an ordinary shell command.

Comment: If `echo '$(file < $@)'` prints nothing then your target file is empty or this recipe is never executed. To clearly distinguish between the two try `echo 'X$(file < $@)X'`. We could spend some time trying to fix your recipe but it is so incredibly far from the make philosophy that rewriting all this in a more make-ish way is probably more reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem.  Your original example didn't make clear what you were actually trying to do:

```
$(COMPDIR)/%.d: $(COMPDIR)/%.cpp
        $(CXX) -o $@ ...
        $(file > $(@),$(foreach path,$(file < $(@)),...)))
```

That is the first line in your makefile creates the target, then you use make functions to try to manipulate the target.

This cannot work, because make will expand *all* macros (variables and functions) for *all* lines in the recipe before it attempts to run the first command.  So by the time the `$(CXX)` command is started make has already expanded the `file` commands (which resulted in reading an empty file if `$@` doesn't exist or, even more confusingly, the *previous* version of the file if it does exist).

I've often wondered why make behaves this way as I can see no good reason for it and it causes a lot of confusion, but that's the way it's worked for 30+ years now.

You will need to either (a) use shell commands rather than make functions to manipulate the generated file, or (b) put the invocation of the compiler inside a `$(shell ...)` function in the recipe so it's run during the expansion of the recipe as well.